# AWS S3 security best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a large scale platform that requires tight documents security between organizations.

### The data designed as follow:

User (has one or many) User Roles
User Role (belongs to) Organization

We use Cognito for authz.

Should I create IAM for each user role under each organization (in thousands)? or is there easier way to achieve this?

e.g.

1. user_1 and user_2 signup to the system
2. user_1 upload image to
   private bucket
3. user_2 should have access to the file (not the
       case)

Comment: Hi, so is this is that cognito roles need to access an S3 bucket. Any way you can provide how they should be used?

Comment: I added more explanation at the end of the question.

Comment: Right so all users should have access to uploaded images?

Comment: users under the same organization

Comment: Ideally you'd create groups and assign a user to the group and create a role per user group.